# OpenFileDialogs on C# MTAThread application

Tags: c#, winforms, console, openfiledialog

Ok, I know that OpenFileDialogs needs STAThread, but i want to start the form from a console application, so I create a Thread for the Form that way I can print things to the console while working with the form, the problem is that if I want to use OpenFileDialogs then I can not print to the console!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Console Output from a WinForms Application**
http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/